# how to return key-value list from a hash map

Tags: java, hashmap, key-value

The input is a hash map, such like

```
HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
}
```

I would like to write a method that return list of type Class A, which had key, value attributes with String type, and the key-value from hashmap.

How to make it real?

Comment: you mean you have a class A which has 2 attributes: String key; String value; and you have to create a list of these objescts while getting the values from the hashmap, right?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Java 8**, you could do something like this:

```
List<Entry<String, String>> list = hashmap
    .entrySet() // Get the set of (key,value)
    .stream()   // Transform to a stream
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Convert to a list.
```

If you need a list of elements of type `A`, you can adapt:

```
List<A> list = hashmap
    .entrySet()   // Get the set of (key,value)
    .stream()     // Transform to a stream
    .map(A::new)  // Create objects of type A
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // Convert to a list.
```

assuming that you have a constructor in `A` that looks like that:

```
A(Map.Entry<String,String> e){
    this.key=e.getKey();
    this.value=e.getValue();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<A> listOfA= new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            A aClass = new A(key, value);
            listOfA.add(aClass);
}
return listOfA;
```

Comment: Why copy to an instance of class `A` when the data is already in a `Map.Entry`?

Comment: I don't know, but since the OP wants it this way I just provided with a solution, though I am completely agreed with what you said